# There is no undo option after removing (or un-saving) a saved item

Tags: feature-request, status-review, user-experience, saves

There is no undo button in the temporary success message, after unsaving a saved item.

The menu items are already very close together so what if I click the wrong option by accident?
I can't undo it.
[image: usability bug with stack overflow]
[image: there is no undo option, usability flae]

Comment: cross-site duplicate of [Can there be a way to undo un-saving a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382622/997587)

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) now adds an undo button for resaving. It also already adds bulk-moving checkboxes in your saved lists, and a quick-move dropdown in the toast immediately after saving a post in Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My userscript [SavedPostsHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) now adds an **undo button** for resaving.

It previously also adds bulk-moving checkboxes in your saved lists, and a quick-move dropdown in the toast immediately after saving a post in Q&A.

Userscript **SavedPostsHelper** ( [source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) | [*install*](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) )

#### Screenshots

1. After saving a post on Q&A, dropdown to move post to list:

   [image]
2. After unsaving post on Q&A pages AND saved list pages,
   adds an "Undo?" button in the toast:

   [image]